# adding runat="server" changes the behaviour of the layout

Tags: asp.net, css, layout, html

I have a page with some controls, usercontrols etc.

when I change a div from plain `<div id="foo">` to a `<div id="foo" runat="server">`
the layout complete changes.

why is that and how can I prevent it?

I'm using 2.0 .NET framework

Is it because .NET changes my id, which obviously I don't want?

Comment: Give us a code sample so we can better understand your situation.

Comment: Do you have any server-side code that applies to all controls (controls with runat="server"), like adding custom attributes or styles?

Comment: Or better yet, do your divs have ID's for CSS styling?  Adding runat="server" will likely change the ClientID for that control when it's rendered, breaking your CSS.

Comment: Do you have a CSS targeting foo?
#foo
{
  //Styles that affect layout
}

That's what my answer below is a response to.

Comment: As JaCraig says, you don't have much choice in .NET Webforms. If you were to go with .NET MVC then your Ids wouldn't be changed but you'd lose the application lifecycle and webcontrols of Webforms.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're targetting the ID of the div control in CSS and then running the control at server, you'll find it no longer applies the style.

This is because ASP.NET has a built in mechanism (INamingContainer) to ensure than you don't have multiple controls named the same. It does this by adding container prefixes so you end up with:

```
<div id="ctl00_ctl00_myDivName" runat="server" />
```

The easiest way around this is to change it from working on an ID to working on a class:

```
<div class="myDiv" runat="server"></div>
```

Alternatively, I believe that XHTML requires that Divs have closing tags so use

```
<div runat="server">Some content</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you add runat="server" to a div, the system automatically generates the ID for it. It's referred to as ID mangling. Unfortunately there isn't much that you can do in the 2.0 framework for divs that I'm aware of (without it being a pain anyway), but in 4.0 we're getting an override... On custom controls though (in 2.0) you can override the ClientID and UniqueID fields. So if you created a MyDiv class that used the div as a base and then created the ClientID/UniqueID fields you should be ok.

Your other option would be to update your CSS/javascript to use the mangled ID. It's fairly static based on the position within the page as ASP.Net uses it to find a control during postback.

Comment: I'm surprised you'd suggest using a mangled ID in the styling, it would mean if you ever changed the control hierarchy the CSS wouldn't apply any more. Bad practice in my book. Swapping it to use an class is a much more maintainable option.

Answer (score 0):

Add **ClientMode="static"** this will make sure your id is not changed to the clientside id for your control.