# show content div runat='server'

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

html

```
<div id="ltrProducts"  runat="server"></div>
<div id="a"  runat=server style="display:none">abcd</div>
```

code

```
string contantProduct = "<div style='cursor:pointer;border:1px solid red' onclick=\"$(\'#a\').css('display','inline');\">does not see water else swimer good</div>";
ltrProducts.InnerHtml = contantProduct;
```

this code does not show `div.a` but if remove `runat='server'` show `div.a`

Comment: is there a reason why u dont have quotes around "server"?

Comment: And shouldn't it be "innerHTML", not "InnerHtml"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you using runat="server" in any tag, ASP.NET is going to hijack whatever id you set and change it to something like ct100_blah_blah_a. Do a View Source in your browser, and look at the actual HTML being output. Then grab the real id of your "a" element, and use that in the javascript.

Comment: have you tested what u claim?

Comment: im no good at the .net stuff but i think the clientID will be changed on every `postback`?? shouldn't it be done like `<div id="a" name="contentDiv">` and access it through JS/jquery like `$('#'+<%=contentDiv.ClientId%>)`...

Comment: +1 referencing ClientId is a good idea. I think theoretically, it could change, but I've honestly never had a problem with it. I believe it was more of a concern about if some update to .net were to change the naming scheme, but I've been using #ct100_... in my javascript for years now.

Ibu: check the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/897738/adding-runat-server-changes-the-behaviour-of-the-layout