# Getting a AJAX CalendarExtender value from a textbox using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I would like to know how to read the value from the TextBox and assign to another TextBox  on button click. This TextBox is attached to the AJAX CalendarExtender. So far I have this. I need this on ShowDate() function in Javascript.

```
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" runat="server"  ReadOnly="false" Height="28px"    Width="283px"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:CalendarExtender  ID="ClendarExtender" BehaviorID="CE1"   TargetControlID="txtStartDate" runat="server">
    </asp:CalendarExtender>

    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtShowMessage" runat="server" Height="76px" 
        style="margin-left: 336px" Width="306px"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnCreateNote" runat="server"  OnClientClick="showDate()"  style="margin-left: 456px" 
        Text="Button" onclick="btnCreateNote_Click" />
    <br />
```

then my js is

```
 function showDate() {
 var txtDate = document.getElementById('<%=txtStartDate.ClientID  %>');
 document.getElementById("txtShowMessage").value = txtDate;
 }
```

Dont know what's wrong and no value is there in the textDate.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your Javascript `showDate()` method like

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
        function showDate() {
            var txtDate = document.getElementById('txtStartDate').value;
            document.getElementById('txtShowMessage').value = txtDate;
        }

</script>
```

I checked this function and it works fine, Hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks Rahul and asifsid88, I changed it accordingly and is working. Also getting the ID that sets up by ASP.NET and doing is a new idea and will try that sometime.

Comment: if it solves then don't forget to accept it as a answer,ur welcome

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you write `runat="server"` then ASP engine prepends some string from its side.
ASP.NET has a built in mechanism (INamingContainer) to ensure than you don't have multiple controls named the same. It does this by adding container prefixes.

So

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtShowMessage" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

will change to something like

```
<input type="text" id="ctl00_ctl00_txtShowMessage" runat="server" />
```

So just `document.getElementById('txtShowMessage')` won't work. You need to get the complete ID. So you can use `document.queryselector('[id$=txtShowMessage]')`. This means get the element whose ID is ending with `txtShowMessage`.
Otherwise you can do like this

```
document.getElementById('<%=txtShowMessage.ClientID  %>');
```

**Note**
1. The second approach I mentioned is better (Using the `ClientID`).
2. If you want to know the complete ID, then go to the webpage and view it's source, locate that TextField and check the ID (It won't change everytime, thats fixed)
3. For more information Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6632976/show-content-div-runat-server)