# adding runat=server causing css not be applied

Tags: css, asp.net

I added `runat="server"` to one of the `div` in my `.ascx` file.

```
<div id="logo" runat="server">
```

This changes the final HTML to below. Notice how the `mainheader1` was inserted

```
<div id="mainheader1_logo">
```

I read this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/897790/886569 and made this change to the html

```
<div id="logo" class="logo" runat="server">
```

This causes the final HTML to be

```
<div id="mainheader1_logo" class="logo">
```

In my CSS the logo class is defined like this:

```
#logo
{
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:78px;
    width:396px;
    height:50px;
}
```

How can i fix this issue in a safe way? I don't want to add the component name in my CSS file as that seems dirty. Also would not want to change the `#` to a `.` because that might break lots of other things.

Comment: Are you found certain control named `mainheader1` in ASPX page? We don't know where autogenerated `mainheader1` comes from without checking other HTML elements.

Comment: I am using a master page. It's the name of that.

Comment: This issue probably comes from master page's naming container, as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/master-pages/control-id-naming-in-content-pages-cs). Are you already tried to use `ClientIDMode="Static"`?

Comment: Additionally, also check if `controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion` exist in web.config and tell what value it currently has (seems that you're using `3.5` mode).

Comment: You have just stumbled across asp.net webforms [name mangling](http://codesoul.com/post/2010/10/01/Componentized-Web-Pages-ASPNET-Name-Mangling-and-CSS-Specificity.aspx) . There is actually reasonable reasons behind this behavior. Either take Tetsuyas advice with `ClientIDMode`, use class instead of id or, the most drastic measure, move to MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Update your css as below. CSS Selector `[id$="logo"]` will select every element whose `id` `ends with "logo"`.

```
[id$="logo"]
{
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:78px;
    width:396px;
    height:50px;
}
```